# Recover formatted ntfs files from ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ntfs, format, ext2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free NTFS partition recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/47613/free-ntfs-partition-recovery)

I had Windows XP running on my system and i installed Ubuntu which deleted all my drives and created a single drive in ext2 format. Now is there way i can recover my files.

I had two drives C: and D: and now there is just one drive with Ubuntu on it
Any help appreciated

Comment: Have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/47613/free-ntfs-partition-recovery http://superuser.com/questions/130131/free-data-recovery-software http://superuser.com/questions/81798/expectations-for-ntfs-file-recovery

Comment: Step 1: STOP USING THE COMPUTER IMMEDIATELY.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is not a lot what you could do. It sounds like you have deleted you windows partitions and install linux into a partition taking that space. During the installation this partition is newly formatted. Hence all of your data has been overwritten.

There might be a possibility that a forensic lab could find some "shadows" of the old data, since the magnetic information is not totally erased, but this is a very, very expensive process.

Sorry, to bring you bad news, please next time make backup before!

Comment: -1 inaccurate. Data carving tools like `foremost` and `PhotoRec` can actually be surprisingly effective even in this situation, provided that the drive was only 'quick formatted' and not completely zeroed out. (Yes, I am speaking from experience.)

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the solutions in other threads I would suggest [scalpel](http://www.digitalforensicssolutions.com/Scalpel/). This is also a software for NTFS recovery.

Comment: But the OP wrote a whole new filesystem to the drive. Even with NTFS recovery programs, the partition table and all the partition data was overwritten when Ext2 was created.

Comment: OK, so I misunderstood. In fact a forensic lab is the only thing which may help, but usually you don't want to spend that amounts of money.