# Deleted my Movies on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I accidently moved my videos folder into my music folder, well, I thought deleting it in my music folder wouldn't disturb my videos in my video folder. Now all my videos are gone, and I tried system restore, but it didn't restore the videos, how do I get them back now?

Answer (score 1):

**[Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) recovers deleted files pretty well.**

Note the sooner you use this software, the less chance there is of overwriting the data in these files. I would even download/install this software to a different partition (and use a boot disk, if you have one!)
Windows just marks the files as deleted so the space can be used in the future.

Comment: in addition i'd probably give phototorec a shot as well. and naturally do the attempted restore to another drive

Answer (score 0):

[File Scavenger](http://www.quetek.com/download.htm) is the best recovery tool I've tried---and unfortunately, I've had to try a lot. I've even bought the full version of it.

I think the free version should be enough, but I might be mistaken. It's a small price to pay, and you'll know what to do the next time something like this happens.

It is important to remember, that before recovering something on a hard drive, it is of utmost importance to use the hard drive in question *as rarely as possible*. It is a particularly bad idea to install or download large files to your new hard drive. The reason for this is that you might write over the otherwise recoverable video files.

This is basically all you need to know. If File Scavenger won't cut it, it is unlikely you'll be able to recover the files. At least that will give you some piece of mind and allow you to leave it at that, as unfortunate as it is.

Good luck!

**NB:** There seem to be [other answers](https://superuser.com/questions/183162/how-can-deleted-files-be-recoverd-closed) to this question, but none that I can't vouch for personally. They may as well work, and you might want to try them out after File Scavenger.