# External Hardrive on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-vista

By mistake I formatted my Windows Vista while installing Ubuntu. Few people suggested me to use Photorec to get the data back. I just installed TestDisk on my machine. My question is: I want to recover the lost data onto an External Harddrive, but when I am trying to connect this drive, its giving me an icon on the desktop and when I try to open it, it shows few folders and executables to unlock the drive.. when I actually click on it. it throws some error.

Comment: The actual error would help!

Answer (score 0):

If you've written ***any*** data to that disk then you've overwritten some files.  The more you use the drive the more you'll overwrite.  You must stop using it immediately if you want any chance of recovering data.

A quick search of this forum for the word [recover](https://superuser.com/search?q=recover) found me a few threads, such as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/181135/recover-data-from-full-format-on-ntfs-partition) and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/181135/recover-data-from-full-format-on-ntfs-partition).