# need to recover Word document after format

Tags: windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover data from full format on NTFS partition](https://superuser.com/questions/181135/recover-data-from-full-format-on-ntfs-partition)

I had 2+ documents, journals, and they were fully viewable on my external when I was ready to format my Vista laptop. After format, only 16 pages of one (shoulda been 140+ pages) and 0 of the other were saved/viewable/available on the external. Otherwise it seems to have saved everything else. Naturally, pretty much the only documents I want.

Comment: What have you tried already, and what problem are you facing in recovering them?

Comment: Re the dupe: Doesn't sound like the external was formatted, as the OP seems to state that most of the data is there, just not what is needed.  It's just too vague as is to offer any help; it's a great story about a problem, just not a very good question as-is. ;)