# Retrive Microsoft Outlook 2007 information after format

Tags: hard-drive, microsoft-outlook, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover data from full format on NTFS partition](https://superuser.com/questions/181135/recover-data-from-full-format-on-ntfs-partition)

I'm trying to retrieve back information (i.e; emails, contacts, ...etc) of Microsoft Outlook 2007 after the hard disk (C drive) has been formatted? How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recover data from full format on NTFS partition](http://superuser.com/questions/181135/recover-data-from-full-format-on-ntfs-partition) and/or [Recover data loss from accidental quick format](http://superuser.com/questions/11160/recover-data-loss-from-accidental-quick-format) and [Many many more](http://superuser.com/search?q=recover+after+format)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to obtain a data recovery program to obtain the Outlook configuration files. Those location of those files depend on your OS as described in this Microsoft help [document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/where-does-microsoft-office-outlook-2007-save-my-information-and-configurations-HP010066914.aspx).

You'll need to run the recovery program and hope it can recover the files.  The format method, whether additional data has been written or erased from the drive, and the data recovery method used, all affect your probability of success.

If you get a good program (such as [Kroll Ontrack)](http://www.krollontrack.com/data-recovery/recovery-software/), have not written, erased, or altered any other data on the drive, you have a fair chance of success of getting some if not most of your Outlook configuration files back.

If you pay for a commercial/industrial grade level of recovery (which raises the cost quite a bit more), your odds improve greatly.