# Gparted: during a partition resize my NTFS partition gone, how can i recover it?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ntfs, gparted

i was using Gparted on Ubuntu 10.04 to resize `/dev/sda5` and free up 1 GB of space. during the operation it gave a failure and now the partition is unknown, no type, no data.

the disk was 20.0 GB and now is 19.0 GB.

unfortunately i have no backup of partition table. and i did not save the details after error.

now when i use Gparted to check the partition, it fails.

what shall i do to recover the data on partition?

**PS**
gparted_resuls.html:

```
GParted 0.5.1

Libparted 2.2 Check and repair file system (ntfs) on /dev/sda5  00:00:00   ( ERROR )
         calibrate /dev/sda5  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
         path: /dev/sda5 start: 31455333 end: 71296469 size: 39841137 (19.00 GiB) check file system on /dev/sda5 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
         ntfsresize -P -i -f -v /dev/sda5
         ntfsresize v2.0.0 (libntfs 10:0:0) Device name : /dev/sda5 NTFS volume version: 3.1 Cluster size : 4096 bytes Current volume size: 21476172288 bytes (21477 MB) Current device size: 20398662144 bytes (20399 MB) ERROR: Current NTFS volume size is bigger than the device size! Corrupt partition table or incorrect device partitioning?

========================================
```

**PS**:

i used **testdisk** tool to back table to the partition. i first hit **Anaylse**, then** deep Analyse**, then **Write** into the `/dev/sda5/` (the lost partition).

then `reboot`. but system crashed and i forced to switch power off.

now i can't even login to gnome. it says **install failure** in startup and each time i enter user/pass it returns me to the login screen again.

what to do next?

**SOLVED**

after using testdisk and then entering windows, windows checked the disk using CHKDSK and then everything with the lost partition was OK.
the only problem now is that my gnome has gone!

Comment: Did you save the results of the operation? If so, please paste it in here. If not, do you remember the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free NTFS partition recovery](http://superuser.com/questions/47613/free-ntfs-partition-recovery)

Comment: i added the gparted detail

Comment: Please paste using the "code" (101010) option instead of the "quote" option. The "quote" option removes line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the linux app "testdisk" to analyse the table, and write it out onto the disk

Comment: thanks @sirex. i did so. but my gnome crashed too!