# NTFS (USB) drive recovery in Windows

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, ntfs, usb-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free NTFS partition recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/47613/free-ntfs-partition-recovery)

Have a USB drive. Doesn't show up in My Computer, but when I plugged it in Autoplay pops up and then hides after a couple minutes without me interacting with it.

I'm getting CRC errors when I try to fix it with Scandisk.

The drive is borked, for sure. What are the best tools to recover ANY available files?

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

I've had reasonable success with [Glary Undelete](http://www.glarysoft.com/products/utilities/glary-undelete/), and it's free (beer).