# how do i recover files and directory structure of an NTFS volume that was formatted as ext4?

Tags: ntfs, ext4, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free NTFS partition recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/47613/free-ntfs-partition-recovery)

last night (at an hour i should have been asleep) i installed ubuntu 10.10 0 onto a disk partition that had many files. the partition was ntfs fomatted to ext4 ! ubuntu 10.10 is bootable in it. i dual boot ubuntu 10.10 with windows 7. how do i recover the data / directory structure from this partition?

Comment: @leogrey Hello! Glad to have you on ServerFault. Your question would be best served on SuperUser.com. It will be moved there shortly where you should get some better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Note that some of the data that used to be in the NTFS partition is almost certainly permanently lost, having been overwritten by Ubuntu's files. Much of the data is probably recoverable, though. You'll need a tool that can scan the drive for file entries that don't have any file table describing them. The only good tool I know of for this purpose is [R-Studio](http://www.r-studio.com/), a favorite of computer repair shops. Unfortunately, R-Studio isn't cheap: the baseline version will set you back US$50.

Remember: DON'T install R-Studio on the drive you're trying to recover. Install it on a different computer and transplant the drive.