# Repair very corrupt NTFS drive?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free NTFS partition recovery](https://superuser.com/questions/47613/free-ntfs-partition-recovery)

I have an external NTFS drive with an absolutely trashed NTFS File System. Is there any recourse for recovering this drive? I have already tried chkdsk using a windows machine. I am running Mac OS X 10.7 and I am very learned in computers and such so don't be afraid to be technical.

Comment: You should not be afraid to be technical either.  Can you tell us what happened when you ran `chkdsk` (output, error messages, etc.)?  What happens when you connect it?

Comment: Okay, Nothing happens when connected. and the chkdsk was very ambiguous and said it could not complete the operation.

Comment: Connect to a windows PC motherboard and use spinrite 6 on it...http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm

Comment: Need exact text/output of `chkdsk` if possible.  I would remove it from the enclosure if it's not a disk with built-in encryption (check manufacturer's website) and see if you have better luck with it directly connected to a IDE or SATA port.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working with a MacBook and all I have available to me is USB, I do have a SATA to USB kit around somewhere, I'll try that. Also I'm thinking about using GParted Live, will that help?

Comment: Never fear, [TestDisk is here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerious tools, some that can be booted CD/DVD image that allow recovery of the data even for deleted files by scanning the hard disk from start to end to find each file regardless of NTFS Master File Table (MFT) corruption.

In most cases you can recover most of the files, including ones you deleted months ago.

After you have the data off, reformat it and reuse if the drive is physically working.

Comment: Previously I have used OnTrack and this works a treat, but it costs. There are free ones available. In mosts cases I would suggest against trying to repair if it is really bad and you want the data.