# How to recover quick-formatted (Windows NTFS disk, formatted by Mac) HDD?

Tags: windows, mac, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Free NTFS partition recovery after disk was formatted in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/47613/free-ntfs-partition-recovery-after-disk-was-formatted-in-mac-os-x)

I accidentally connected a Windows NTFS HDD to a Mac. The Mac was in a foreign language (Italian) and I (maybe) quick-formatted the HDD. I think that the information is there, but the FAT table is gone. How can I recover the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running it through [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step), a free cross-platform partition recovery tool. If the format was indeed of the quick variety then the actual data on the disk will not have been affected.

If TestDisk fails, you can also try it's companion app [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step), which can recover files from a drive by examining the raw contents of the drive for file patterns.

Comment: Those two are the best free programs of their kind that I've encountered.